# How to delete a div with id slider using ReactJS?

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to delete div section without using state, how to remove this? I tried by using unmountComponentAtNode but showing the error

> unmountComponentAtNode(): The node you're attempting to unmount was rendered by React and is not a top-level container. Instead, have the parent component update its state and rerender in order to remove this component.

Code:

```
 import 'rc-slider/assets/index.css';
    import 'rc-tooltip/assets/bootstrap.css';
    import React from 'react';
    import Tooltip from 'rc-tooltip';
    import Slider from 'rc-slider';
    import { withStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
    import Icon from '@material-ui/core/Icon';
    import { unmountComponentAtNode } from 'react-dom';

    const createSliderWithTooltip = Slider.createSliderWithTooltip;
    const Range = createSliderWithTooltip(Slider.Range);
    const Handle = Slider.Handle;
    const marks = {
      0: <strong>0°C</strong>,
      26: '26°C',
      37: '37°C',
      50: '50°C',
      100: {
        style: {
          color: 'red',
        },
        label: <strong>100°C</strong>,
      },
    };

    const handle = (props) => {
      const { value, dragging, index, ...restProps } = props;
      return (
        <Tooltip
          prefixCls="rc-slider-tooltip"
          overlay={value}
          visible={dragging}
          placement="top"
          key={index}
        >
          <Handle value={value} {...restProps} />
        </Tooltip>
      );
    };


    class StepSlider extends React.Component {
      constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = { sliderValues: [80] };

        this.onDelEvent = this.onDelEvent.bind(this)
      }

      handleChange = sliderValues => {
        this.setState({ sliderValues });
      };
      onDelEvent = (e) => {
        console(e)
        var object = this.refs.slider;
        unmountComponentAtNode(object);
        document.body.removeChild(object);
      }
      render() {
        const { classes } = this.props;
        const { sliderValues } = this.state;
        return (

          <div className="row" style={{ margin: '50px' }} ref="slider" id="slider">

            <div className="col-md-11">

              <div className="box-header" style={{ textAlign: 'center', fontSize: '20px' }}><strong>Project NPV: $2.98M</strong></div>
              <p style={{ position: 'absolute', color: 'pink' }}>kjh</p>
              {/* <Slider min={0} max={100} marks={marks} defaultValue={sliderValues} onChange={this.handleChange} handle={handle} tipFormatter={value => `${value}%`}/> */}
              <Slider
                min={0} max={100} marks={marks} defaultValue={sliderValues} onChange={this.handleChange} handle={handle} tipFormatter={value => `${value}%`}
                trackStyle={{ backgroundColor: 'blue', height: 15 }}
                handleStyle={{
                  borderColor: 'red',
                  height: 35,
                  width: 35,
                  marginLeft: -14,
                  marginTop: -9,
                  backgroundColor: 'white',
                }}
                railStyle={{ backgroundColor: 'black', height: 15 }}
              />
            </div>
            <div className="col-md-1">
              <Icon className={classes.icon} color="primary" onClick={this.onDelEvent.bind(this)} style={{ marginTop: '45px' }}>
                remove_circle</Icon>

              {/* <div style={wrapperStyle}>
              <p>Range with custom handle</p>
              <Range min={0} max={20} defaultValue={[3, 10]} tipFormatter={value => `${value}%`} />
            </div> */}
            </div>
          </div>
        )
      }
    }
    export default withStyles({ withTheme: true })(StepSlider);
```

Comment: simply how to remove a DOM element in reactjs without using state

Comment: Please, provide a minimal example, not your actual production code as it contains lots of unrelated information.

Comment: Is there a particular resason why you do not want to use `isSliderVisible` state for example but looking for alternative solution?

Comment: i created a div with some data and button in it, now i wanna delete that div from react DOM by clicking a button inside it.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest the following pattern for dynamic removal of sliders:

**Slider.js**

```
const Slider = ({ id, onRemove }) => (
  <div className="slider">
    <button onClick={() => onRemove(id)} />
  </div>
);

export default Slider;
```

**StepSlider.js**

```
import Slider from './Slider';

class StepSlider extends React.Component {
  state = {
    sliders: [
      {id: 1, value: ...},
      {id: 2, value: ...},
      ...
    ]
  }

  handleRemoveSlider = id => {
    this.setState(prevState => ({
      sliders: [...prevState.sliders.filter(slider => slider.id !== id)]
    }))
  }

  render() {
    this.state.sliders.map(slider => (
      <Slider id={slider.id} onRemove={this.handleRemoveSlider} />
    ))
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import 'rc-slider/assets/index.css';
import 'rc-tooltip/assets/bootstrap.css';
import React from 'react';
import Tooltip from 'rc-tooltip';
import Slider from 'rc-slider';
import { withStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import Icon from '@material-ui/core/Icon';


const createSliderWithTooltip = Slider.createSliderWithTooltip;
const Range = createSliderWithTooltip(Slider.Range);
const Handle = Slider.Handle;
const marks = {
  0: '5%',
  10: '6%',
  20: '7%',
  30: '8%',
  40: '9%',
  50: '10%',
  60: '11%',
  70: '12%',
  80: '13%',
  90: '14%',
  100: '15%'

};
const handle = (props) => {
  const { value, dragging, index, ...restProps } = props;
  return (
    <Tooltip
      prefixCls="rc-slider-tooltip"
      overlay={value}
      visible={dragging}
      placement="top"
      key={index}
    >
      <Handle value={value} {...restProps} />
    </Tooltip>
  );
};
const handleStyle = {
  borderColor: 'red',
  height: 28,
  width: 28,
  marginLeft: -14,
  marginTop: -8,
  backgroundColor: 'white',
}

class StepSlider extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super()
    this.state = {
      sliders: [
        { id: 1, title: 'Discount Rate', value: '5' },
        { id: 2, title: 'Total Volume', value: '10' },
        { id: 3, title: 'Avg Sales Rate', value: '50' }
      ]
    }
    this.handleRemoveSlider = this.handleRemoveSlider.bind(this);
    this.onChange=this.onChange.bind(this)
  }

  onChange=(e)=>{    
    let inputValue = e;
    let statusCopy = Object.assign({}, this.state);
    statusCopy.value = inputValue;
    this.setState(statusCopy);
   }

  handleRemoveSlider = id => {
    this.setState(prevState => ({
      sliders: [...prevState.sliders.filter(slider => slider.id !== id),
      ],
    }))
  }

  render() {
    return (
      this.state.sliders.map(slider => (
        <div>
          <Button id={slider.id} onRemove={this.handleRemoveSlider} title={slider.title} value={slider.value} onChange={this.onChange}/>
        </div>
      ))
    )
  }

}
export default StepSlider;



const Button = ({ id, onRemove, value, title,onChange }) => (

  <div className="row" style={{ margin: '50px' }} id={id}>
    <div className="col-md-1">
      {title}
    </div>
    <div className="col-md-10">
      <Slider min={0} max={100} handle={handle}
        defaultValue={value} marks={marks}
        tipFormatter={value => `${value}%`}
        trackStyle={{ backgroundColor: 'blue', height: 15 }}
        handleStyle={handleStyle}
        railStyle={{ backgroundColor: 'black', height: 15 }}
        onChange={onChange}
      />
    </div>
    <div className="col-md-1">
      <button onClick={() => onRemove(id)} style={{ backgroundColor: '#1a237e', color: 'white' }}>X</button>
    </div>
  </div>
);
```

Actually this is working, i mean deleting slider by passing its respective id but state is not updating and i wanna update the particular slider value onchanging it. please check and help me